# how to extract data frame inside a pandas data frame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

from a pandas data frame(3 * 5), how to extract a column (with rows containing data frame objects as values(each row data frame of 2 * 10) ) into a separate data frame(6 * 10 rows)

```
log_df['df_inside'] = log_df['input'].apply(lambda x :parser(x))
```

parser(x) returns a data frame(2 * 10) for each row after apply.
After the above step, how to extract out df_inside data frame from the log entries?

Comment: I think (row data frame of 210 must be row data frame of 2*10). To get the values from a DataFrame, you can do `log_df['df_inside'].to_list()`.

Comment: want df_inside as a separate data frame

Comment: `df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': log_df['df_inside'].to_list()})`

Comment: or: `df2 = pd.DataFrame()` and then `df2['a'] = log_df['df_inside'].to_list()`

Comment: didn't work df2 looks the same as log_df['df_inside'] which still have 2*10 data frame objects.. expects 10 columns rather than single column 'a'

Comment: Perhaps you can show what `log_df['df_inside']` looks like ...

Answer (score 1):

pd.concat(log_df['df_inside'].tolist()).reset_index(drop=True) worked

Comment: thanks! that saved me. I was looking for that answer for a while.